# Apache Spark count records per group with nullables values

Tags: java, apache-spark

When I try to calculate records number per group I see, that group with nulls has not records but this is not correct.

Input DataFrame:

```
+--------+
|    Name|
+--------+
|  Andrei|
|  Andrei|
|    null|
|    null|
|Grigorii|
+--------+
```

Code:

```
Dataset<Row> df = inputDf.groupBy("Name")
            .agg(functions.count("Name").as("Name_count"));
```

Actual DataFrame:

```
+--------+----------+
|    Name|Name_count|
+--------+----------+
|    null|         0|
|  Andrei|         2|
|Grigorii|         1|
+--------+----------+
```

Expected DataFrame:

```
+--------+----------+
|    Name|Name_count|
+--------+----------+
|    null|         2|
|  Andrei|         2|
|Grigorii|         1|
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
Dataset<Row> storageFrame = leftDataset.groupBy("Name")
            .agg(functions.count("*").as("Name_count"));
```